# MySQL: Can/Should my MIN() and MAX() queries be combined?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's a *simplified* version of what I'm currently doing.

A)

```
SELECT id, foreign_key_id, type, quantity, MAX(price) AS price // <--- Max
FROM quotes
WHERE type = 'tier 1'                                          // <--- Equal
AND prod_id_requested = 12345
```

B)

```
SELECT id, foreign_key_id, type, quantity, MAX(price) AS price // <--- Max
FROM quotes
WHERE type != 'tier 1'                                         // <--- NOT equal
AND prod_id_requested = 12345
```

C)

```
SELECT id, foreign_key_id, type, quantity, MIN(price) AS price // <--- Min
FROM quotes
WHERE type = 'tier 1'                                          // <--- Equal
AND prod_id_requested = 12345
```

D)

```
SELECT id, foreign_key_id, type, quantity, MIN(price) AS price // <--- Min
FROM quotes
WHERE type != 'tier 1'                                         // <--- NOT equal
AND prod_id_requested = 12345
```

Is there a good way for me to save some resources and maybe combine these into fewer queries?
Or is this pretty much the way to do it?

[**UPDATE**]
Here's some sample data to play with:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `quote_item` (
  `id` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `quote_id` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `product_id_quoted` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `product_id_requested` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(52) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` float(10,4) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

INSERT INTO `quote_item` (`id`, `quote_id`, `product_id_quoted`, `product_id_requested`, `type`, `price`, `quantity`) VALUES
(1, 1, 12, 12, 'tier 1', 0.0100, 100),
(2, 2, 1, 12, 'tier 3', 0.0038, 8200),
(3, 2, 13, 12, 'tier 2', 0.0041, 10000),
(4, 3, 7, 14, 'tier 1', 0.0060, 25000),
(5, 3, 8, 12, NULL, 0.0180, 250),
(6, 3, 9, 15, NULL, 0.0019, 5000),
(7, 4, 12, 12, NULL, 0.0088, 7500),
(8, 4, 16, 12, 'tier 1', 0.0040, 10000),
(9, 5, 12, 9, 'tier 2', 0.0089, 1200),
(10, 5, 12, 12, 'tier 1', 0.0072, 6400);
```

Ultimately, we want to nicely pack up all the data into an array.
Currently, we are getting a row from each query (no GROUPing) where we have the actual *ID*, *Qty*, *etc*... for the single row with the Min value, as well as that same info for the single row with the Max price, per "type" category, then building the array.
For example:

```
$flash_report = array(
    'tier1' => array(
        'qty' => array(
            'min' => array(
                'id' => 1
                ,'quote_id' => 1
                ,'price' => 0.01
                ,'quantity' => 100
                )
            ,'max' => array(
                'id' => 8
                ,'quote_id' => 4
                ,'price' => 0.004
                ,'quantity' => 10000
                )
            ,'sum' => array(
                'value' => 16500
                ,'count' => 3
                )
        )
        ,'price' => array(
            'min' => array(
                'id' => 8
                ,'quote_id' => 4
                ,'price' => 0.004
                ,'quantity' => 10000
                )
            ,'max' => array(
                'id' => 1
                ,'quote_id' => 1
                ,'price' => 0.01
                ,'quantity' => 100
                )
        )
    )
    ,'other' => array(
        'qty' => array(
            'min' => array(
                'id' => 5
                ,'quote_id' => 3
                ,'price' => 0.018
                ,'quantity' => 250
                )
            ,'max' => array(
                'id' => 3
                ,'quote_id' => 2
                ,'price' => 0.0041
                ,'quantity' => 10000
                )
            ,'sum' => array(
                'value' => 25950
                ,'count' => 4
                )
        )
        ,'price' => array(
            'min' => array(
                'id' => 2
                ,'quote_id' => 2
                ,'price' => 0.0038
                ,'quantity' => 8200
                )
            ,'max' => array(
                'id' => 5
                ,'quote_id' => 3
                ,'price' => 0.018
                ,'quantity' => 250
                )
        )
    )
)
```

[**/UPDATE**]

Right now, I'm getting all the data from our individual queries, then assembling it all into a big-ol' array.
I'm thinking there's ***got*** to be a better way to do this :)

Comment: Granted the queries are simplified/obfusicated, but people like me will focus on the lack of `GROUP BY` which means the results could arbitrary due to [MySQL's GROUP BY support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html).

Comment: @omg-ponies Thanks. The question has now been updated with more info to better clarify what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: BTW, I put the desired outcome as an array. Not only because it's how I plan to pkg the data, but also (and mostly) because I think it's the easiest to understand. ... I hope that's the case for others as well :)

Answer (score 3):

You can combine it all:

```
SELECT "equal" as condition,
       MAX(price) AS max_price,
       MIN(price) AS min_price
  FROM quotes
 WHERE type = 'tier 1'
 GROUP BY 1
UNION
SELECT "not_equal" as condition,
       MAX(price) as max_price,
       MIN(price) as min_price
  FROM quotes
 WHERE type != "tier 1"
 GROUP BY 1
```

I like this better than the CASE solutions (although those are more succinct) because it is completely SQL92 conforming.

I removed the id, foreign_key, and qty fields because I didn't think you intended to have the aggregates grouped on the keys and was wondering why you'd want them grouped on the qty too.

Comment: At this point I'd stick a UNION in between your 4 individual statements in your original question, along with adding a new field named "condition" (like in my answer) with the 4 distinct values "min_notequal", "min_equal", max_notequal, "max_equal".

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT id, foreign_key_id, type, quantity, 
    MIN(case when type != 'tier 1' then price end) as MinNotTier1Price,
    MIN(case when type == 'tier 1' then price end) as MinTier1Price,
    MAX(case when type != 'tier 1' then price end) as MaxNotTier1Price,
    MAX(case when type == 'tier 1' then price end) as MaxTier1Price
FROM quotes
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, 
       foreign_key_id, 
       type,
       quantity, 
       MAX(case when type = 'tier 1' then price else NULL end) AS price_max_eq,
       MIN(case when type = 'tier 1' then price else NULL end) AS price_min_eq,
       MAX(case when type <> 'tier 1' then price else NULL end) AS price_max_neq,
       MIN(case when type <> 'tier 1' then price else NULL end) AS price_min_neq,
FROM quotes
```

Answer (score 0):

You can at least combine A and C as well as B and D like so

```
SELECT id, 
       foreign_key_id, 
       type, 
       quantity, 
       MAX(price) AS max_price, 
       MIN(price) AS min_price
FROM quotes
WHERE type = 'tier 1' 
GROUP BY id, foreign_key_id, type, quantity


SELECT id, 
       foreign_key_id, 
       type, 
       quantity, 
       MAX(price) AS max_price, 
       MIN(price) AS min_price
FROM quotes
WHERE type != 'tier 1' 
GROUP BY id, foreign_key_id, type, quantity
```